# Cross Platform Commercial Development Tool / IDE / Programming Language ( Native )

Tags: delphi, cross-platform

Is there a Cross Platform ( Win32 / Win64 / Linux32 / Linux64 / MacOSX Snow Leopard ) Commercial Development Tool / IDE / Programming Language ?

( No Java / .Net , only NATIVE )

---

From the answers i'am understandig ( my understanding) there is not any single Comercial Tool/IDE/Programing language ( combined all toggether ) for native cross platform development ( platforms in the question ) !!!

And I 'am asking for a Comercial product , having in mind the "quality" of the microsoft visual studio or the RAD Studio ( delphi . c++ ).

I looked at Freepascal/Lazarus but it give not the impresion of a "full quality product" ( sorry guys , nice but way way far from Delphi or VS , any way keep the good work )
.

Thank you all for the interest , I will keep searching , any new information will be helpfull.

And I like to apologise for my english ( not native !! to me , learned what i know by my self).

Sebastian.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account into your registered one. Sorry that it took us two years to do that :)

Comment: Right now the answer is no, but in 12 months time I would bet on Delphi having everything covered as native development (Win32/Win64/Mac OSX/iOS/Linux/Android). That WOULD be impressive!

Answer (score 18):

Embarcadero (the current owner of Delphi) has promised a cross-platform version (win32. Mac, Linux) in the near future... Check the Delphi road map (by product manager Michale Rozlog) on their developer web site (dn.codegear.com) for more details.

It will be a native compiler for each platform, according to the current, limited, information available.

Comment: Pulsar (beta for Delphi XE2) includes only Win32, Win64, OSX and iOS compilers. Due to Embarcadero follows one year development cycles the autumn of 2012 would be an earlier date for Linux and Android support.

Comment: Delphi XE2 with Mac support shipped in 2011. Still waiting for Linux!

Answer (score 8):

What exactly do you need? A Tool or a IDE or a Language? Why it has to be commercial?

You tagged this Question with "delphi", so I expect you looking for a cross patform IDE/Compiler.

For what I know, the only native cross platform compiler is [FreePascal](http://freepascal.org/), you can use the Delphi 7-Like IDE [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) with that compiler. But both aren't commercial, but opensource.

In a few Months (nobody knows exactly when) there [will be](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2009/05/20/38885) a new cross platform Delphi.

Comment: Afaik that change will only incorporate crosscompilers, no cross platform development IDE.  And support for the 64-bit platforms will take another year, since only scheduled for the release after the next (with the current annual schedule that would be november 2011)

Answer (score 4):

Embarcadero Delphi XE2 is now in beta test, native support for MacOS and 64 Bit is included, support for Linux is announced - see  http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/64-bit
and [What should be tested in 64-bit Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549276/what-should-be-tested-in-64-bit-delphi)

---

Another (commercial but inexpensive) toolkit is wxForms for Delphi, based on wxWidgets:

> "wxForms for Delphi is an integrated
>   form designer plugin for CodeGear
>   Delphi that helps you to create cross
>   platform applications for Windows Mac
>   OSX and Linux  using single source
>   base.
>
> wxForms code from Delphi can be
>   compiled in Mac OSX and Linux without
>   much change using FreePascal/Lazarus."

http://www.twinforms.com/products/wxformsdelphi/index.php

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Qt library](http://qt.nokia.com/products) recently bought by Nokia. You can use it in C++ but there are bindings in many languages for example [this is the python binding](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt). 
You can choose from three different type of licenses (commercial, LGPL or GPL)

Answer (score 1):

There's also [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) and the UI designer tool [DialogBlocks](http://www.dialogblocks.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There's also [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) for C++ only. And if you add multiples plugins you can consider [vim](http://www.vim.org/) and [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). With the latter two you can use any development language.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not free and I haven't used it in awhile, Metrowerks Codewarrior used to be cross platform, not sure if it is still around or not though.

Answer (score 0):

Qt + Qt Creator + GCC (or perhaps some other compiler on Windows, such as the MS Visual Studio Express Edition compiler).  Qt provides great support for building cross-platform GUI applications, Qt Creator provides a uniform IDE, and then you just need the appropriate compiler for your platform.

Qt Creator is open source, and Qt is available in both open source and commercially-licensed versions (although the open source version is suitable for commercial development these days due to its use of the LGPL).

Answer (score 0):

[CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=148) is a powerful one click installation package for cross platform native development. It already supports **4 CPU/OS hosts** (Win32, Win64, Linux32, Linux64), and **16 CPU/OS targets** (arm-Wince, arm-Linux, arm-Embedded, arm-gba, arm-nds, i386-Win32, i386-Linux, i386-FreeBSD, i386-Haiku, x86_64-Win64, x86_64-Linux, x86_64-FreeBSD, powerpc-Linux, powerpc64-Linux, sparc-Linux, sparc-Solaris). More are supported in **Lazarus/FreePascal**, but others are not yet integrated in CodeTyphon. Did I mention that it is free?

One code to rule them all ;-)